# Generalize the product rule

Tags: calculus, analysis

for the pointwise product $fg$ where $f:\mathbb{R} ^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
and $g: \mathbb{R} ^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$

So I know how to do it if g was $ \mathbb{R} ^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ but with these terms the product doesn't quite add up to what it should be..

Any help?

Comment: Wouldn't it still be $Df\cdot g+f\cdot Dg$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most abstracted language the product rule becomes

$$D(f\cdot g) = (Df)\cdot g + f\cdot (Dg)$$

where the $Df, Dg$ are whatever the deriviative is for functions of these dimensions and the products whatever multiplications you need between such objects. $Df$ being the gradient and $Dg$ being the Jacobian.

Effectively the product function in this case is just $g$ where each component function has been multiplied by $f$. I trust you understand what I mean by

$$h_i = fg_i$$

The deriviative of a vector valued function is essentially the matrix defined by

$$\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}$$ (Call it the Jacobian if you want)

This you can just evaluate with the one dimensional product rule

$$\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}g_i +  f\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} $$

which may be reprenseted in a variedy of different styles and notations the the one above is perhaps the more formal while I personally often like the notations used in the Landau books

$$\frac{\partial (f\mathbf g)}{\partial \mathbf x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x} \mathbf g + f \frac{\partial \mathbf g}{\partial \mathbf x}$$